# Correct way of scaling data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scale

I am using a TensorFlow to create a simple DNN model.
When I am training my data I am scaling all the train data the following way:

```
X_scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
X_standard = X_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
```

But when I am using my model checkpoint, I have to scale again the input. Therefore I am scaling the single sample, like this:

```
X_scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
X_standard = X_scaler.transform(X_test)
```

But the scaling of the single sample gives me `[[0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 ]]`

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and how can I scale correctly? 
My train data is a csv file and inside looks like this:

```
[[11.000000 61.000000 134217728.000000 ... 0.000000 46596.313072
  272756.723290]
 [1.000000 87.000000 134217728.000000 ... 16.449219 13925.136928
  289477.942990]
 [16.000000 73.000000 2097152.000000 ... 19567.666016 50885.644772
  305358.707758]]
```

My single test sample is the same but is only one element in the array:

```
[[57.000000 14.000000 2097152.000000 5.000000 3.000000 3.000000 0.000000
  262.000000 81788928.000000 1001.000000 527593.000000 349181.000000
  182.000000 11.000000 0.349954 0.701496 95.800000 2.280000 1.790000
  13141380.000000 3166248.000000 19.420000 25.400000 100.740000
  31004.910000 2.000000 1000000000.000000 93.370000 3.030000 3.540000
  11483952.000000 3923548.000000 25.470000 40.370000 186.790000
  49280.940000 18.000000 3700000000.000000 750.371094 17519.000000
  27508.000000 18915.000000 149477.500000 2080774.000000 189943.000000
  0.000325 5.376465 350.303954 370104.379128]]
```

Comment: You're instantiating another `X_scalar` before calling transform on `X_test`? You would be replacing the first `X_scalar` that was fitted to `X_train`, so that's why it doesnt scale properly. Remove the second `X_scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()`.

Comment: I do not think this is the problem since with the first scaler I am creating the model and with the second I am using this created model ckpt and scaling again the input and feeding it in the model.

Comment: No, your model is trained on data that has been scaled a particular way (by your first `X_scalar`), so it expects input during prediction that has been scaled in the *same* way. i.e., you need to apply the first `X_scalar` to your test data as well. Besides, even if this is not the case, you are calling `.transform` method with the second `X_scalar` before it has even been fitted with anything.

Comment: Does it mean that I have to pass `X_scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()` in between the train and the model, save it somehow in TF in the session?

Comment: Troy, I think you are mistaken I believe the scaler method is scaling across the samples, not across the features therefore if I use the following code:
`X_test = [[3, 1, ....... 1, 1]] 
X_scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
X_test_test = X_scaler.fit_transform(X_test)
print(X_test_test)`

 itself gives me again 0s:
`[[0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000]]
`